# Python: Extract different columns and assign to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this df:

```
A  B  C  D
1  2  3  4
```

I want to extract columns 0:1 and 3rd one

But first thought would be:

```
X = DS.iloc[:, 0:1:3].values
```

But, this approach does not work

Comment: Are you specifically hoping to be able to copy specified integers (i.e. be able to manipulate how you select these? Are you hoping to have an array? Or is a df just fine... I'd suggest maybe something like `df1 = df[['A', 'B', 'D']]` might be just fine. Depending on your use case and requirements.

Comment: @SharpDev Thank you, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If really you need to work with ranges, use [`numpy.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to combine them:

```
out = df.iloc[:, np.r_[0:2,3]]
```

If you know the columns, be explicit:

```
out = df[['A', 'B', 'D']]
```

Output:

```
   A  B  D
0  1  2  4
```